Не получается подключить ,базовые стили и компоненты tailwind в react.app

Все остальное сделано по инструкции:
yarn add tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */ // В tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

